# Styling inline within a span

Tags: css

I'm trying to get `this.toggleFormatter(task)` to float to the right. It currently has `display: inline-grid` on it so that it is next to the link, but I can't get it to move right and stay inline. Flexbox and float doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

```
return {
    text: (
        <span className="tree-toggle-spacing">
            <Link to={'/tasks/' + task.id}>
                <Label bsStyle="info">T{index+1}</Label>
                {task.name}
            </Link>
            {/*className="tree-toggle-select" */}
            {this.toggleFormatter(task)}
        </span>
    ),
    nodes: resources
};
```

Comment: Hi can you please post your html and css? Preferrably in a jsfiddle with your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can align elements to the left and right by using the following CSS classes:

```
.align-left { float: left }
.align-right { float: right }
```

To keep everything inline, simply add this code **outside** of both of the elements that have the float classes but **inside** the `div` they are both in: `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`